# Map JSON data from Web API to KnockOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I Have an array as below:

```
 modules: ko.observableArray(),
    pagemodules: ko.observableArray([
        {
            id: "1", name: "name1", description: "", icon: "fa fa-facebook-square", page: "page-8", active: false, children:
            [
                { id: "1.1", name: "name1-1", description: "", icon: "fa fa-film", page: "/home/index", active: false },
                { id: "1.2", name: "name1-2", description: "", icon: "", page: "/home/help", active: false },
                { id: "1.3", name: "name1-2", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "1.4", name: "name1-3", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "1.5", name: "name1-4", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "1.6", name: "name1-5", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false }
            ]
        },
    {
        id: "2", name: "name2", description: "", icon: "fa fa-search", page: "/home/about", active: false, children: []
    },
    {
        id: "3", name: "name3", description: "", icon: "fa fa-heart", page: "page-8", active: false, children: 
            [
                { id: "3.1", name: "name3-1", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "3.2", name: "name3-2", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "3.3", name: "name3-3", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "3.4", name: "name3-4", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false }
            ] 
    },
    {
        id: "4", name: "name4", description: "", icon: "fa fa-envelope", page: "page-8", active: false, children: []
    },
    {
        id: "5", name: "name3", description: "", icon: "fa fa-star", page: "page-8", active: false, children: 
            [
                { id: "5.1", name: "name5-1", description: "", icon: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "5.2", name: "name5-2", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "5.3", name: "name5-3", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "5.4", name: "name5-4", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false }
            ]
    },
    {
        id: "6", name: "name6", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false, children: 
            [
                { id: "6.1", name: "name6-1", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "6.2", name: "name6-2", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "6.3", name: "name6-3", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "6.4", name: "name6-4", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false }
            ]
    },
    {
        id: "7", name: "name7", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false, children: 
            [
                { id: "7.1", name: "name7-1", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "7.2", name: "name7-2", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "7.3", name: "name7-3", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false },
                { id: "7.4", name: "name7-4", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false }
            ]
    },
    {
        id: "8", name: "name8", description: "", page: "page-8", active: false, children: 
            [
                { id: "8.1", name: "name8-1", description: "", page: "page-8.1", active: false },
                { id: "8.2", name: "name8-2", description: "", page: "page-8.2", active: false },
                { id: "8.3", name: "name8-3", description: "", page: "page-8.3", active: false },
                { id: "8.4", name: "name8-4", description: "", page: "page-8.4", active: false }
            ]
    }
    ]),
```

this is the HTML where i bind the data, basically i'm using a knockout widget, so the below code is in \app\widgets\expander\view.html

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: { data: settings.items}">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bind="attr: { href:'#collapse'+$data.id}">
        <h4 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">

            <!--<span data-bind="css: $data.icon"></span>-->

            <a style="padding-left: 10px;" class="collapsed" data-bind="html: $data.name"></a>

        </h4>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="attr: { id:'collapse'+$data.id}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: $data.children">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <span data-bind="css: $data.icon"></span>
                <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#" data-bind="html: $data.id+'.'+$data.name"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is how i use the widget

```
<div data-bind="expander: {items:modules}"></div>
```

modules - get data from WebAPI
pagemodules - harcoded value with same format.

When I bind these values to my accordion control, "pagemodules" works, while "modules" don't. What is the problem here?

here is sample JSON data from my web API:

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"e8c8650d-2756-4abc-82ae-d86a62e5fbc6","Name":"Page1","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":[{"$id":"2","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"2e7a6565-d177-4630-bb77-07f58dc6e7f9","Name":"Page1.2","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"3","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"64248745-5a17-496b-97d4-4fbdae5a2f92","Name":"Page1.1","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"4","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"b065d3f3-5dd6-4adb-918d-bb07f7e5c4e2","Name":"Page1.3","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"5","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"11da74d4-403d-41ef-a870-bc48da7b1dc7","Name":"Page1.5","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"6","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"18271cf5-5e5e-401d-96ca-ce5214b98049","Name":"Page1.4","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null}]},{"$id":"7","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"23ddb73c-4319-48e0-b9f7-f96e10b76306","Name":"Page2","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":[{"$id":"8","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"5edab097-58fd-41f8-b12f-202a76c787ea","Name":"Page2.3","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"9","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"139cb94f-6dcc-408f-ac69-5ab0ff1555ed","Name":"Page2.1","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"10","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"745532d0-9ea1-4462-b7e2-b9189cc2da72","Name":"Page2.2","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null}]},{"$id":"11","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"3042928a-a01f-459e-bd84-f6a9c19f30b8","Name":"Page3","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":[{"$id":"12","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"21336001-d0c2-4066-ad7a-24c1291dfd53","Name":"Page3.1","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"13","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"9d654b2c-7f1b-4e48-94d4-42fc50d4a6a6","Name":"Page3.3","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"14","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"06ba9de8-97c9-4736-a83a-56a12fd5dc7e","Name":"Page3.2","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"15","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"e3e98162-599b-4233-aa5d-6cb6fd1a4d50","Name":"Page3.4","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"16","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"609376d4-a354-4c52-8512-a98d039a68ed","Name":"Page3.5","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"17","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"2b44d16c-148e-4a51-b728-cb3dd3d72b86","Name":"Page3.7","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null},{"$id":"18","$type":"MyApp.Domain.Model.Module, MyApp.Domain","ModuleId":"0b6f3c82-fdfd-46dc-8d86-d98a4d00f530","Name":"Page3.6","Description":null,"Icon":null,"Children":null}]}]
```

EDIT: 
Here is what is different,maybe something wrong here. The "modules" which get from the web api are handled in this way:

```
 attached: function () {
        var self = this;
        var modules = unitofwork.usermodules.all()
                            .then(function (modules) {
                                self.modules(modules);
                                //console.log(JSON.stringify(modules, undefined, 2));
                                console.log(modules);
                            }
        );

        return Q.all([modules]).fail(self.handleError);
    },
```

Edit :

here is some code on how the JSON is used by Breeze to return me the "unitofwork.usermodules.all()".

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from(resourceName)
                .orderBy("name asc")
                .expand("Children");

            return executeQuery(query);

function extendModule(metadataStore) {
        var moduleCtor = function () {
            this.moduleId = ko.observable(breeze.core.getUuid());

        };

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Module', moduleCtor);
    };
```

I think maybe the code above might be a problem?

Comment: is it possible to add a working sample in jsfiddle.net and share the link?

Comment: Hi Sherin, I know it would be helpful. have tried to fork some code and apply mine. but it get a bit complicated. basically i know where the problem is. my webAPI returns the JSON correctly but the Breeze entity manager is might be the problem.

Comment: It would help a lot if the code would be a lot more trimmed, and like @SherinMathew said if it'd be an actual repro. If we can't repro the scenario it'll be very hard for us to help you (especially with so much mostly irrelevant code). GL!

Comment: Just check that setting the moduleId to a new uuid is not overwriting the moduleId coming from the webApi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the Model in web API, as solved the problem. Here is the new model. Seems like i have missed the "ParentModuleId" as foreign key to the Children. Thanks for all the help. :)

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Module
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ModuleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ParentModuleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentModuleId")]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Children { get; set; }
}
```